# Lighthouse scoring for progressive web app

Tags: progressive-web-apps, lighthouse

https://yourstop.info is a PWA. When I run lighthouse on it, the PWA score comes up as 73 and performance as 60, see image below.

[image]

It is giving a time to interactive of 19.1 seconds which is the reason for the low scoring. What happens on startup is that when the user's location is determined, a list of relevant bus stops is downloaded in the background. The code for this is

```js
  var firstLocationUpdate = false;
  //var firstLocationUpdate = true;
  
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(updatePosition, showError, geoOptions);
  }
  else {
    window.ys.userLocationError = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser";
  }

  function updatePosition(position) {
    if (position != null) {
      window.ys.userLat = position.coords.latitude;
      window.ys.userLon = position.coords.longitude;
      
      try {
        // When google maps was not loaded this was throwing an exception
        window.ys.userLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(window.ys.userLat, window.ys.userLon);
      }
      catch (e) {
        console.log("Google maps not loaded when initializing geo.js, userLocation LatLng not set");
      }

      window.ys.userLocationError = "";

      if (window.ys.userLocation != null && window.ys.userLocationTripMarker != null) {
        window.ys.userLocationTripMarker.setPosition(window.ys.userLocation);
      }
      if (window.ys.userLocation != null && window.ys.userLocationSearchMarker != null) {
        window.ys.userLocationSearchMarker.setPosition(window.ys.userLocation);
      }
      
      if (firstLocationUpdate == false) {
        var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent('firstlocationupdate', true, true);
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
        firstLocationUpdate = true;
      }
    }
  }
```

This does however not impact at all on the readiness of the PWA, the page is already fully rendered and the user can perform other tasks while the background function is in progress. If in the code snippet above, *firstLocationUpdate*  is initialized to *true* and the background download is prevented, then the lighthouse scoring is much higher as shown here

[image]

Both cases however show the exact same user experience as far as I can tell. But the benefit of doing the background stop download is that the *Locate the Nearest Stops* operation happens much quicker.

The problem with the lower score for PWA is that chrome no longer automatically display the web app install banner. So I am in a situation where I need to make a choice and my current preference is for the background download to occur.

So the question is, is there a workaround which will allow me to have BOTH a high PWA score AND do the background download ?

Or is there any way of influencing how lighthouse scores PWAs, in my eyes anyway the background download resulting is lighthouse lengthening the time to interactive is not correct behavior ?